# Can I deploy application with user-specific info via Active Directory?

Tags: deployment, active-directory, windows-installer

Currently the application in question can be downloaded from our website after logging in with email address. Then during download we inject the user credentials to the executable, thus after installation, the user's email address is automatically available in the app.

Our aim is to allow installing this app via active directory in a way that the email address of the user (to whom the app is assigned) is injected.

Is it possible somehow? E.g. using MSP, MST files with the MSI?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Active Directory deployment you need and MSI package. However, this does not solve your problem completely.

An MSI package can be configured to receive the email address as a command line parameter when installing. The problem comes from the deployment process, i.e. when you deploy through Active Directory you need to set a command line that is valid for all users, as the package will be installed on all on the selected/specified computers. This means that you have no option to specify a unique email address for each user.

A workaround would be to have a custom action included in the MSI package that reads the email address from the user's computer and uses it in your installation package. This would mean that your users would need to have the email address stored in a known location (registry entry or file), which you can read with your custom action (C# or C++ code, DLL generated as output).

Comment: Thank you, Bogdan. Isn't possible then to enquire AD for the email address of the user?

Comment: not that I know of. I recommend to ask this question about AD to a dedicated admin, that works daily in the AD environment. I am specialized in building the packages, not deploying them.